# Activity, FragmentActivity Foreground Time

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Does a Android Activity has some options to know how many seconds was visible to the user

Or I must to calculate every seconds that was visible using **onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, onRestart, onDestroy**

Answer (score 0):

That's right. If you wanted to track across all of your applications activities you could declare an abstract activity class which they all extend from and perform the relevant time tracking in the callbacks mentioned above.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity/AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //saveTime
    }

    ...
}
```

.

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way ,if you don't require high accuracy

```
public class TestImpl implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
      //do something here,such as recording time,use differents tag .
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
       //do something here,such as save the data to the database with your tag .
    }
}
```

last,upload data at the right time !

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way you are suggesting is one of the most appropriate method to calculate the activity visibility time.

**Steps**

Inside `onResume` start handler like

```
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume()
  If(mHandler==null){
    mHandler = new Handler()
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000)
  }
}



Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       mCountSeconds++;
       mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
};
```

Now you can remove callback inside `onDestroy`

```
public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy()

   // Here you can measure time in seconds simple access mCounterSeconds
  If(mHandler != null){ 
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
  }
  //here you can save counter value into db, sharedprefs, file... 

}
```

After all, you will get  `mCountSeconds` now you can save it into a database or file or anywhere you want.